# Angular : retrieve html element from all components

Tags: angular

I have a big project, and I want to customize button style by adding a ripple style whenever I click any button inside any component , So I added the style for the ripple in the global styles.scss, Where can I add my JS function that should trigger the click event on any button in any component ?

Answer (score 0):

Without any source code I can't give specifics, but check out the directive documentation: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#handling-user-events

That links to an example of handling events on an HTML element to change the color. You should be able to do the same thing with your ripple effect